# Spring MVC - servlet requested source not available

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I tried to make a simple web app with Spring MVC and I follow this tutorial from Netbeans:

```
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html
```

And I get the problem: `The requested source not available ?`

My questions:

1. What is this problem from ? [ I'm quite sure it is from servlet - Tomcat ]
2. How to fix this

Comment: Show us (a) your `web.xml`, and (b) your Spring context file.  Also, check your tomcat log (`catalina.out`), see if there's an error in there.

Comment: Also, depending on your configuration, the url you are trying to access along with the code for the servlet you think should be configured to respond to that url

Comment: Definitely not enough information... if there is no deployment error, then check the application specific files (netbeans would have created). May be it added a context path...

Comment: Thanks all, I compress the project and run on my friend's laptop. It's fine, maybe there are problems when I run my project. Thanks for all of your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I compress the project and run on my friend's laptop. It's fine, maybe there are problems when I run my project. Thanks for all of your effort :)